# Very low, difficult to see, SILENT, Aircraft

Tags: aircraft-identification

I live in Oklahoma, and at about 7-7:30 pm on 11/20/22, something massive flew over my house(going east), bigger than any cargo plane I have seen. It was completely silent, with 3 red lights along the bottom (one in front, middle and rear). Extremely difficult to see, almost blending in to the sky. And moving very slowly. It did not look like it had wings, so I don't think it was a plane. I am prior Air Force, and grew up near Beale AFB, and have seen air craft my whole life. Does anyone here, know what the heck this is?

I thought maybe a blimp, but I have seen blimps before, and those make noise. This made NONE.

Comment: Are the lights the only thing you saw of it, or did it have any other visible form?

Comment: Silent, slow, and difficult to see = very high up?  Maybe sunlight at dusk reflecting off of the bottoms of a formation airliners approaching an airport?  Anything from area 51 probably would not have its lights on.

Answer (score 4):

there are apps which allow you to fly large numbers of drones (with lights on them) in precise formation by remote control. It could have been three drones, high enough to make their motors hard to hear above background noise.